# Not able to click "Continue to Step 3" via my selinium test suite (Tried with id , className and xpath)

Tags: selenium

```
public class UIRegistrationBwinbe { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver//chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://test.www.bwin.be/");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("REGISTER NOW")).click();
        WebDriverWait waita = new WebDriverWait(driver,100);

       // wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("Input_ContactData_EmailAddress")));driver.findElement(By.id("Input_ContactData_EmailAddress")).sendKeys("junk@gmail.com");
       driver.findElement(By.id("Input_NameData_FirstName")).sendKeys("chan");
       driver.findElement(By.id("Input_NameData_LastName")).sendKeys("chan");
       driver.findElement(By.id("continueToStep")).click();
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("Input_LoginData_Username")));
       driver.findElement(By.id("Input_LoginData_Username")).sendKeys("zzchanzz1");
       driver.findElement(By.id("Input_LoginData_Password")).sendKeys("123qwe");
       driver.findElement(By.id("Input_SecurityData_SecurityQuestion")).sendKeys("My spouse's middle name?");
       driver.findElement(By.name("Input.SecurityData.SecurityAnswer")).sendKeys("junk");
       driver.findElement(By.id("Input_BirthData_DateOfBirth_Day")).sendKeys("01");
       driver.findElement(By.id("Input_BirthData_DateOfBirth_Month")).sendKeys("Jan");
       driver.findElement(By.id("Input_BirthData_DateOfBirth_Year")).sendKeys("1992");
       //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("continueToStep")));
       //driver.findElement(By.id("continueToStep")).click();
       //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("nextStep")));
       //driver.findElement(By.className("btn-l3")).click();
       //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='continueToStep']")).click();
       driver.findElement(By.id("continueToStep")).click();
    }
}
```

I'm getting an exception that element is not visible in "continue to step".

Tried with id, className and xpath.

Comment: Limit your code block to the exact lines of code where you are blocked

Comment: can you add relevant html ?

Comment: <div id="continueToStep" class="btn-l3">
                    <button name="nextStep" type="button">Continue to Step 3</button>
                </div>

Comment: I had to add the whole line of code as the problem occurs in step 2 only , step one i was able to run it smoothly. Hence added both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer after a struggle of so many hours . this piece of code solved my problem. Thanks all for the support

int ok_size=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='continueToStep']/button")).size();
 System.out.println(ok_size);
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='continueToStep']/button")).get(ok_size-2).click();

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the html you posted in the comments -

```
<div id="continueToStep" class="btn-l3"> <button name="nextStep" type="button">Continue to Step 3</button> </div>
```

It looks like your not trying to click the button but the div container, try:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("nextStep")).click()
```

The error you are receiving could also be because there are multiple elements that share the same id/xpath/name etc.

Comment: still receiving the error
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible